# How to get the hostname of mac os in C

Tags: c

I 'm trying to get the hostname of my school mac os. I can't use `gethostname()` as it's in section 3 of the man pages of my school macs, instead of section 2. Is there another way of getting the hostname, without using `gethostname()`? I'm only allowed to use `libc` functions in  `man 2 section`.

Comment: first : http://linux.die.net/man/2/gethostname, second : why does it matter what section of man pages?

Comment: Why is the section of the manual page that `gethostname()` is documented in a problem? (on BSD-derived systems, section 2 documents system calls only, while library functions are in section 3)?

Comment: workaround: `f = popen("hostname")` then read `f`

Comment: I'm only allowed to use functions in `man 2 section`.

Comment: @TenTen-Peter: That restriction is quite arbitrary. On Linux `gethostname()` is a system call (section 2), while on other system it's a libc function (section 3). You might want to talk to your instructor.

Comment: @dhke I did he told me, there's another way of getting the `hostname`.

Comment: @TenTenPeter On Linux? Yeah, It's in `/proc/sys/kernel/hostname`. On OS/X you need `sysctl()`, which is also in section 3.

Comment: So ask him. Asking us is somewhat like cheating, isn't it?

Comment: Hmm, your teacher forces you to use platform-dependent functions instead of standard functions? No strcpy? not strlen? No `printf`, etc.? Is that Apple-iHigh? I somewhat suspect he did not understand what the section numbers mean.

Comment: @Olaf yes, we have to implement those functions ourselves.

Comment: "I want to do <common thing>, but I'm not allowed to use <normal solution>." is a silly homework assignment. In fact, it's pretty counter-productive for learning good programming skills. Anyway, `gethostname` on MacOS is implemented here: http://opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-1082.50.1/gen/FreeBSD/gethostname.c unfortunately for you, sysctl is also a section 3 function, so you might want to figure out how that's implemented from the same source.

Comment: @dhke:You can find `gethostname` in Linux in section 2 **and** 3! 3 is for standard functions (libc, POSIX), 2 for platform-dependent stuff. General rule in programming: use the most standard way (for C: C standard, then other standards, then platform) applicable. **Teaching** something different is worse than just a bad idea.

Comment: @Olaf I do not know where you get that distinction. Section 2 is for **system calls** and section 3 is for **library** functions. Nicely enough, Linux doesn't have a `gethostname()` system call, so section 2 is the wrong place for it. And you might want to tone down quite a bit, I'm pretty sure OP is by now quite aware that he won't write portable code.

Comment: @dhke: Sorry, I was a bit imprecise (got that from unix.stackexchange, btw.). You are right, but that does not change the actual point. Fist one should use section 3 functions. Only if those are inappropriate, use system-calls.

Comment: @Olaf I was actually quite astonished that Linux still has the "old" distinction, but yes it has. And ... well ... in fact you shouldn't care if a function wraps a system call or if it's implemented in another way. As long as it's portable and documented. But depending on the teaching scenario, I do see value in "try to get this on your own", but only if it is made clear that you shouldn't ever do this for portable c ode.

Comment: @dhke: I don't see what's "old" about that. To me it is quite reasonable. Btw. according to Wikipedia OSX uses the same cathegories (I don't use it, so cannot verify). And `gethostname` actually **is** standard (POSIX), so my fault was not too off for this question.

Comment: @Olaf old != bad. OS/X has a FreeBSD-based userland and retains that sectioning system. Linux retains those, which I just find interesting, since GNU --for me-- has a history of jumbling around things.

Comment: @dhke: That was not even my point. The phrase "old" implies a "new" distinction. Which would be - what? And GNU is not Linux. After all, Linux keeps an attitude of POSIX-compliance and AFIK, that scheme indeed is POSIX - or at least POSIX-derived.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`gethostname` is just a `sysctl`, and `sysctl` is just a `syscall`.
And syscalls are (per definition) in section 2 of the manual.

So grab your favourite disassembler (or `otool -tV` if you have none), `nm` the libraries in `/usr/lib/system` to find out which ones export `_gethostname` and `_sysctl`, and get to work (or look up the source :P).

Below I re-implemented `gethostname` using `sysctl`, and `sysctl` using `syscall`:

```
#include <sys/syscall.h>    // SYS_sysctl
#include <sys/sysctl.h>     // CTL_KERN, KERN_HOSTNAME
#include <unistd.h>         // syscall

int sysctl(int *name, u_int namelen, void *oldp, size_t *oldlenp, void *newp, size_t newlen)
{
    return syscall(SYS_sysctl, name, namelen, oldp, oldlenp, newp, newlen);
}

int gethostname(char *buf, size_t buflen)
{
    int name[] = { CTL_KERN, KERN_HOSTNAME };
    size_t namelen = 2;

    return sysctl(name, namelen, buf, &buflen, NULL, 0);
}

int puts(const char *s)
{
    // left as an exercise to the reader ;)
}

int main(void)
{
    #define BUFSIZE 256
    char buf[BUFSIZE];
    size_t buflen = BUFSIZE;

    if(gethostname(buf, buflen) == 0)
    {
        puts(buf);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The implementation of `sysctl` isn't too complicated; you really just slap `SYS_sysctl` (from `sys/syscall.h`) in front of the other arguments and pass them all on to `syscall`.

To understand the implementation of `gethostname`, you have to know how `sysctl` works:

- `oldp` is where the queried value will be stored.
- `newp` is where the new value will be read from. Since we're not setting any new value, this is `NULL` here.
- `name` is more or less the actual list of arguments to `sysctl`, and its contents depend on the actual `sysctl` being queried.

  `CTL_KERN` denotes that we want something from the kernel.
  `KERN_HOSTNAME` denotes that we'd like to retrieve the hostname.
  And since `KERN_HOSTNAME` doesn't take any arguments, that's all there is to it.

  Just for demonstration, had you called `KERN_PROCARGS`, `name` would require an additional argument, namely the process ID of which the arguments should be retrieved.
  In that case, `name` would look like this:

  ```
  int name[] = { CTL_KERN, KERN_PROCARGS, pid };
  ```

  and `namelen` would have to be set to `3` accordingly.

Now in the above implementation I've made use of `puts`, which you're obviously not allowed to do, but I trust you can figure out how to re-implement `strlen` and use the `write` syscall with that. ;)

Comment: We are no "do my homework" site. Giving hints should have sufficed, posting all code will not really help OP improve his research or coding skills.